# Writing standard input to file via adb on android

Tags: android, linux, io, adb

I have a following problem:
I need to save files on the android device using adb however I can't save this files on developing computer due to sercurity reasons. That basicly means I can't use adb push.

I was thinking about some kind of tool that I will run as "adb shell" command which will automatically write everything that I put on standard input of this tool to a predefined file.

Can anybody suggest what can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `adb` [SYNC protocol](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/adb/SYNC.TXT) in your program, so it would be able to upload your files from a memory buffer instead of a disk file.

Comment: Do you have some example (in C# or java) that show the file transfer using this. (I mean what need to be sent to socket in order to push file) ?

Comment: I don't have an implementation in C# or Java. You can find the C version in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/file_sync_client.c

Answer (score 0):

You can use script command after this everything will be written in specified file

```
script -f filename
```

Refer http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_script.htm for more information

Comment: On my device there is no script command. Do you know where can I download binaries so I can deploy it before use?

Comment: Also, as I've checked this command will probably save all the standard output also?

Comment: You can compile busybox with script command selected and install new busybox

Comment: yup, I have found the busybox, but I will probably use tee command. Will write what the outcome is

Comment: None of the above give any positive solution. Need to stick with adb SYNC PROTOCOL